# iOS 8 seemingly ignoring meta viewport initial-scale

Tags: iphone, ios8, viewport

I have a site which I am trying to get to site perfectly in all mobile devices. for that purpose i set  viewport meta like below

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

It seems works perfectly on the most of the devices but on the iOS devices, it seemingly ignores the meta viewport tag. I tried workarounds like

1: Added the meta tag with some delay

`<body onload="javaScript:onloadHandler();">`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onloadHandler() {
        var meta = document.createElement('meta');
        meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
        meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;');
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
        if (typeof window["bodyOnload"] != 'undefined') {
            bodyOnload();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Result : Most of the time it doesn't show the zoom level correctly. Some times the page is top left cornered.

2. Calculated the scale from device pixel ratio and used that scale value for initial scale.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var scale = 1 / window.devicePixelRatio;

   var viewportTag = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=" + scale + ", maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no\"/>";     

   document.write(viewportTag);        

   </script>
   ```

Result : it doesn't show the zoom level correctly.

It looks the issue is with initial-scale value.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get it to the correct zoom level with iOS 8?

EDIT:

This issue comes from iOS 8. The scaling issue happens only when the user tries to open multiple popup windows. There is one bug with popup windows with iOS 8. Hope the scaling issue will be fixed once Apple fixed the issue with popup windows.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved with new update for 8.1.2.